# Is it possible to render a component during eval in halogen?

Tags: purescript, halogen

In my halogen project have this eval branch:

```
 eval (SetTest tName next) = do
      H.set (State Nothing)
      detail <- H.fromAff $ toAff settings $ getTestsByTestname (tName ^. unTestName)
      H.set (State (Just detail))
      pure next
```

The toAff bit if off doing AJAX and may take a while to return. In my render function I have

```
, case ts of
              Nothing ->
                HH.div [class_ BS.centerBlock]
                  [HH.i [classes (HH.className <$> ["fa", "fa-spinner", "fa-spin", "loading"])]
                     []
                  ]

              Just td ->
                HH.h3_ [HH.text $ td ^. tdName<<<unTestName]
```

I'm naively expecting to see a loading spinner when until my aff action returns, but it looks like the eval runs all the way through before the html is rendered. Is this correct?

*edit*

Turns out this was user error - I was calling my Query in wrong order. Future mes: setting the state does indeed update the ui :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, modifying the state during `eval` should indeed trigger a render. Unless your `Aff` isn't really async, I'm not sure why you wouldn't be seeing what you expect here.

Have you tried doing something like `H.fromAff $ later' 5000 $ pure <some value>`? Where `later'` comes from `Control.Monad.Aff` and `<some value>` is something suitable for `detail`. You should see the loading spinner for 5 seconds then, before it resolves to `<some value>`.